# php array returns undefined but print_r shows otherwise

Tags: php, arrays, json, undefined

```
foreach($jsonmediationinfo as $value1) {
    echo $value1['mstatus'];
    print_r($jsonmediationinfo);
}
```

Output:

```
1Array ( [0] => Array ( [mstatus] => 1 [mhearingnum] => first [mminutes] => adakjaflafjlarjkelfkalfkd;la ) [1] => Array ( [mhearingnum] => second [mminutes] => ) [2] => Array ( [mhearingnum] => third [mminutes] => ) )
```

`Undefined index: mstatus in ... on line 265` line 265 is line `echo $value1['mstatus'];`

This is my php server side code.This used to saved data into database but i am getting undefined `index:mstatus` in line 265. But in the `print_r` the index `mstatus` clearly exists. Also if I check in database when I update the data the values changes to correct value. In this example the value is changed to `1`.

What is the problem in this line of code. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: There is no `mstatus` in the second and third array. Probably you need `if(isset($value1['mstatus']))`.

Comment: `mstatus` only exists in the first array, not in the others.

Comment: @user3584460 you can post it as correct answer i will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array you're looping looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [mstatus] => 1
        [mhearingnum] => first
        [mminutes] => adakjaflafjlarjkelfkalfkd;la
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [mhearingnum] => second
        [mminutes] =>
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [mhearingnum] => third
        [mminutes] =>
    )
)
```

Only the sub array at the first index contains `mstatus`, so on the second iteration of the loop it throws the exception. It's best to check if `mstatus` is present using `isset($value1['mstatus'])`.

```
foreach ($jsonmediationinfo as $value1) {
    if (isset($value1['mstatus'])) {
        echo $value1['mstatus'];
        print_r($jsonmediationinfo);
    }
}
```

In a real life scenario you could handle your status like this:

```
foreach ($jsonmediationinfo as $value1) {
    if (isset($value1['mstatus']) && ($value1['mstatus'] === 1 || $value1['mstatus'] === true)) {
        // Do something with the positive status
    } else {
        // Do something with the negative/missing status
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As RuubW mentioned

you could handle real life condition like this also

```
    foreach ($jsonmediationinfo as $value1) {
        if (array_key_exists('mstatus',$value1)) {
            echo $value1['mstatus'];
        } 
        print_r($jsonmediationinfo);
    }
```